# How to add a new line after "> with sed or cat

Tags: ubuntu, sed, regular-expression, cat

I'm fairly new to using cat and sed and have the following lines:

```
<td><a href="//mywebsite.net/page/MyFile_20110101.html">MyFile_20110101.html
<td><a href="//mywebsite.net/page/MyFile_20110102.html">MyFile_20110102.html
<td><a href="//mywebsite.net/page/MyFile_20110103.html">MyFile_20110103.html
```

I am trying to keep only the MyFile_20YYMMDD.html by creating a line break after "> then deleting all lines that contain "> using sed or cat so that the result will look like:

```
MyFile_20110101.html
MyFile_20110102.html
MyFile_20110103.html
```

I am stuck because it seems " and > are characters that aren't supposed to be used when trying to use sed and cat commands so I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done with `sed`

```
$ cat test 

<td><a href="//mywebsite.net/page/MyFile_20110101.html">MyFile_20110101.html
<td><a href="//mywebsite.net/page/MyFile_20110102.html">MyFile_20110102.html
<td><a href="//mywebsite.net/page/MyFile_20110103.html">MyFile_20110103.html

$ sed -i 's/^.*>//' test

$ cat test  

MyFile_20110101.html
MyFile_20110102.html
MyFile_20110103.html
```